# f: R → R and $|f'(x)| ≤ |f(x)|$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

Let $f: R → R $ be a function such that $f'(x)$ is continuous and $|f'(x)| ≤ |f(x)|$ for all $x ∈ R$ , if $f(0)=0$ the maximum value of $f(5)$ is

My Attempt: I proved that $f'(x)=0$ for $x ∈ [0,1]$ through LMVT but i am not able to prove anything further

I also thought of a real life analogy of this that if magnitude of acceleration is always less than magnitude of velocity and initially the particle was at rest then it won't move for every $t>0$ and hence concluding $f(x)=0$ for every $x ∈ R$

Help Please.

Answer (score 1):

By [Gronwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall's_inequality#Differential_form), $f$ is identically zero.

Comment: We have not been taught this inqeaulity.
Can you explain?

Comment: @BelalAhmed The proof is given in the linked article, which can be easily adapted to your special case.

Comment: Okay let me see.
But can't we conclude anything through knowledge of LMVT?

Comment: @BelalAhmed Well, considering that you were able to conclude that $f'(x) = 0$ for $x \in [0, 1]$, you can conclude that $f(1) = 0$. Then repeat whatever your proof was to get that $f(2) = 0$ and so on.

Comment: i undestrood the inequality you gave and converted it to proof my question by taking a special case. 
Thanks